# How to convert a string based timestamp from Unix's date command to a Python date object?

Tags: python, unix, datetime

A variety of programs output date formats according to the syntax of their Unix platforms date command.  For example: `Tue Nov  5 12:38:00 EST 2013`.

*How can I easily convert this into a Python date object?*

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually pretty simple.  You just need to use the datetime.strptime() method which converts a string representation of a date (1st parameter) into a date object based on a directive which specifies that format of the string representation (2nd parameter).

In this case, this is the code you would use:

```
import datetime

unix_date_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
# Matches strings like Tue Nov 5 12:38:00 EST 2013

my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    date_in_string_format, unix_date_format)
```

**Further Reading**
[datetime.strptime() method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)